# Submitting App in correct App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have submitted my app to the app store but it is going to the US app store and I get this error when I try to access it

"The item you've requested is not currently available in the U.K. Store, but it is available in the U.S. Store.  Click Change Store to view this item"

Comment: I am not sure if this is a programming question?

Answer (score 2):

Connect into your Itunes Connect account. Go to 'Manage Your Applications' select your app and then choose 'Rights and Pricing' and click on 'Specific stores'. Add which countries you want your app to be in and save.

Comment: I have done this. Still the link points to US store: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/...

Comment: Have you checked the United Kingdom store? Also, where do you get the link to http://itunes.apple.com/us/app...?

Comment: In itunes connect under "App Information" > "Links" in the App details page. In rights and pricing i have selected United Kingdom only under "Select the App Stores ..."